# What are the teachings of Islam about sperm donation?

Tags: nikah, fiqh

The science has come to such an amazing and miraculous era where heart transplant, kidney replacement and eye replacement operations are taking place. There is also a sperm donation provision, which enables infertile couples to have baby.

Since all these above were not possible in early stages of Islam, there are no related rulings in traditional sources. So what are the implied rules of Islam? Is the sperm donation permissible in Islam, since the woman and the donor wouldn't have actual sexual intercourse?

Comment: [This](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/22126/) is not a direct answer to your question, still you may want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Preservation of lineage is one of the most important objectives (*maqasid*) of *shari'ah*. Since modern technology permits things that people in the past could not even imagine, the rulings in these cases must be derived by analogy and wisdom, keeping in line with the objectives of *shari'ah*.

When the sperm donor is not the husband, this is unquestionably impermissible because one cannot have children with someone other than their wife. The question of lineage becomes murky, and there are all chances of someone's rights being infringed upon (either the child who is entitled to know their lineage and entitled to interaction with the father, the mother who is entitled to child support, or the father who is entitled to his progeny). In addition this whole idea goes against the cohesion of the family unit and in fact disturbs it.

When the sperm donor is the husband and the egg is that of the wife and fertilization occurs outside the womb but the fertilized egg is implanted inside the wife, this is permissible as a case of last resort.

When the fertilized egg is implanted into another woman (a surrogate) this is impermissible as well because it is as if motherhood is shared between two people and one necessarily loses their right (I mean motherhood not only in the genetic sense, but in the sense of all the hormonal changes the pregnant woman goes through and the emotional (and physical!) bond between her and the baby).

References:
http://en.islamtoday.net/node/1335 
http://www.islamqa.com/en/ref/21871 
http://www.islamqa.com/en/ref/83799

Answer (score 1):

Sperm donation in totally refused in all Islamic rules as this sperm is belonged to someone else not the original husband, so the baby will be at the end belonging to the sperm donater, and it can't be named with someone else.

In general this is family confusion, really how can the husband look at this baby knowing it is not even his.

Comment: Where are your references? What is the difference between your answer and @Ghaith answer? Your opinion is more Islamic but still it's your opinion! You don't have references and you got 2 upvotes! Even this sentence is not related to Islam: "really how can the husband look at this baby knowing it is not even his"

Answer (score -6):

From a medical perspective, the thought of sperm donation is similar to transplant in my opinion. Both are allogenic transplant.

The discussion was only about one perspective of sperm donation which is the interaction and lineage- that is a fair point. But imagine this husband and wife - whom (the husband) can't impregnate his wife even with all the medical advancement - are living in a desperate life for a child. Sperm donation is a hope for them to save their marriage separation. In my opinion we should look at the general picture sometime.

That's only a personal but medical opinion.