# Latest views/ruling about egg donation between wives of same man?

Tags: halal-haram, husband-wife, polygamy, pregnancy

Recently, I stumbled upon this ruling https://islamqa.info/en/83799 about taking eggs from one wife of a man and implant the fertilized embryo it into another wife of the same man.

From what I understand from this ruling is that it was first allowed but then deemed not permissible after further discussions. But the argument that has been given to make it not permissible is that the wife that will have the embryo implanted may already be pregnant through the relations from the husband so there will a confusion about the identity of the mothers if she gives birth to twins.

Now, that ruling is from 1404AH (around 1983 and 1984). Maybe, at that time, technology was not that advanced but today's technology can tell us that whether a woman is already pregnant or not at the time of embryo implantation. In this case, most doctors today will not implant the embryo as the woman is already pregnant.

Is there any new ruling in the light of new technology that is available?

and what I know is that Shia muslims are allowed egg donations through a fatwa published in 1999 but sunni muslims are not but that's only my understanding.

P.S: Please stick to the topic of egg donation between the two wives of the same man, not from a stranger woman.

Comment: there is no need of some new technology, that woman just can wait some time without sex to be sure she is not pregnant.

Comment: I think this is related if not already covering the question https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29759/13438

Answer (score 2):

The fatwa you are referring to is based on a declaration of the [International Islamic Fiqh Academy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Islamic_Fiqh_Academy,_Jeddah) from October 1986 it is case 5 from a list of 5 cases which have been considered as haram. And it is explained why:

> It was determined that the first five methods are all haraam according to sharee’ah and are forbidden completely in and of themselves, or because of the results to which they will lead, such as **mixing of lineages**, loss **of motherhood** and other things that are forbidden according to sharee’ah. (source islamqa [#83799](https://islamqa.info/en/83799))

However there is a [fatwa](http://islamport.com/w/ftw/Web/432/4552.htm) which is part of a total of 8 questions on the topic of egg/sperm donation etc. from Mai 1997 made by the scholar 'Atya Saqr عطية صقر which explains in details his qualification on such issues.

There you may read this two options (I'll translate, but shorten the Arabic text to necessary minimum):

> السؤال السادس - إذا كان الرجل متزوجا من زوجتين ، الأولى لا ينتج جسمها بويضات لسبب أو لآخر، أو لا يمكن أن تحمل باستعمال بويضاتها هى، فهل يمكن أن تؤخذ بويضة من الزوجة الثانية تلقح بحيوان منوى من زوج المرأتين ، ثم يوضع الجنين فى رحم الزوجة الأولى لتحمل وتلد ، هل يجوز ذلك ؟ وإذا كان لا يجوز فلماذا ما دام الأب واحدا والعملية كلها تتم داخل إطار علاقة زوجية مشتركة ؟
>   Question 6:
>   If a husband is married to two wives, the first is not able to produce eggs or can't get pregnant by using her own eggs, would it be permissible to take eggs from the other wife which are fertilized by the husbands sperms and place the fetus/embryo in the womb of the first wife?
>   If not why, as the father of that child is the same and the whole intervention is inside a legal relationship.
>
> والجواب: إذا أخذت بويضة الزوجة الثانية الملقحة بمنى زوجها ووضعت بدون إذنها وموافقتها فى رحم ضرتها الأولى كان ذلك حراما ، لأنه اعتداء على حق الغير بدون إذنه ، والكل يعلم ما بين الضرائر من حساسية شديدة ، وأثر ذلك على الأسرة .
>   Answer:
>   If a fertilized egg of the 2nd wife was placed in the womb of the 1st wife without her permission (permission of the 2nd wife!) it is haram, as this an offense of her rights!
>   وإن كان بإذنها وموافقتها يثار هذا السؤال : لماذا يلجأ الزوج إلى هذه العملية؟ إن كان لمصلحة تعود عليه هو مثل كثرة الإنجاب الحاصل من زوجتين لا من زوجة واحدة فقد يكون ذلك مقبولا إن دعت إليه حاجة أو ضرورة ، مع التأكد من القيام بواجب الرعاية الصحيحة ، ومع ذلك لا أوافق عليه لما سيأتى بعد من العلاقة بين الإخوة الأشقاء والإخوة غير الأشقاء .
>   And if it was placed with her permission, we must ask: Why does the husband do this?
>   If it is for a benefit or profit for the husband (like having many children from both wives not from one single wife) it might be acceptable if there's a need, but I wouldn't allow it for what I will explain later about the relation between siblings and half-siblings.
>   وإن كان لمصلحة تعود على الزوجين ، فإن المصلحة العائدة على الزوجة الثانية الصالحة للإنجاب ليست ذات قيمة، بل قد يكون فى ذلك ضرر على أولادها عند تقصير الأب عن الوفاء بحق هذه الكثرة من الأولاد ، أو بضآلة نصيب أولادها من ميراث أبيهم حيث يوزع على عدد كبير من أولاده .
>   If it is for a benefit of both spouses, then the profit for the second wife has no value because of reasons among them: the decrease of the inheritance shares for her children.
>   وإذا كانت المصلحة عائدة على الزوجة الأولى التى لا تنجب فإنها تتمثل فى أمرين هامين ، أولهما إرضاء عاطفة الأمومة وعدم الشعور بنقصها بالنسبة لضرتها ،لكنها لا تتحقق إلا إذا كان أولادها ينسبون إليها ، وقد تقرر-كما سبق ذكره- أنها مجرد أم حاضنة وما ينتج منها فهو لزوجها ولضرتها صاحبة البويضة، فإذا عرفت أن من يولد منها فهو لضرتها فلماذا تتعب نفسها بالحمل والوضع دون فائدة لها؟ إذًا ليست هناك مصلحة لها قيمتها من هذه العملية لكلتا الزوجتين ولا يجوز للزوج أبدا أن يجعل ما تلده الزوجة الأولى الحاضنة أولاداً لها، لمعارضته ما سبق ذكره ولأنهم سيكونون بذلك بالنسبة لأولاد الزوجة الثانية صاحبة البويضة إخوة غير أشقاء ، أى إخوة من أب فقط ، وهذا له أثره فى الميراث إذا توفى أحد الإخوة ، فالأخ الشقيق يحجب الأخ لأب ، والحاضنة إذا ماتت لا يحق لها شرعا أن ترث ممن ولدتهم ولا أن يرثوا منها ، فالأمومة النسبية مقطوعة ، وذلك إلى جانب ما يكون بين الأولاد من كل من الزوجتين من حساسيات معروفة لها اثار غير طيبة .
>   The benefit for the first wife who isn't able to get pregnant seems to be either to satisfy her feelings of motherhood or to let her not feel having any defect. Note that even if she was pregnant with this child it can't be hers. As this children is a child of the egg of the second wife and therefore this woman (first wife) can't inherit from the child that was in her womb (if it dies earlier than her) as she is nothing more than a surrogate mother! So the major issue is the inheritance matter: for example a sibling comes before a half-sibling in the case of inheritance.
>
> وهنا يمكن أن نقول إن المفاسد المترتبة على هذه العملية أكبر من المصلحة العائدة على الزوج والزوجتين والقاعدة الشرعية تقول :
>   درء المفاسد مقدَّم على جلب ،المصالح . ولهذا أرجح عدم جواز هذه العملية ، وإذا كان للزوج رغبة فى كثره الإنجاب فأمامه الوسائل المشروعة الأخرى، مع مراعاة واجب العدل فى معاملة الزوجات والأولاد .
>
> So on the whole the damage in all these cases over weights the benefit and the rule of shari'a says: "**warding off bad things comes before attaining good things**" therefore I prefer not allowing these kinds of intervention

So the basis for not allowing this is the fiqh ruling:

> Warding off bad things comes before attaining good things درء المفاسد مقدَّم على جلب ،المصالح
>
> السؤال السابع - فى الحالة نفسها وهى حالة زوج الاثنتين ، هل يجوز أن تكون إحدى الزوجتين أمًا حاضنة لبويضة ملقحة هى لزوجة الأخرى؟
>   Question 7:
>   In the same case is it allowed to let one of both wives be a surrogate mother for a fertilized egg of the other wife?
>
> الجواب: قلنا: إن الأم الحاضنة لا يجوز لها أن تدخل رحمها ماء غير ماء زوجها، وفى الصورة المذكورة وإن كان الماء ماء زوجها فإن للبويضة ليست لها، وعلى فرض التجاوز فى ذلك إذا كانت حضانتها للبويضة بإذن صاحبتها فإن الآثار المترتبة عليها والتى سبق بيانها فى إجابة السؤال السابق تجعلنى أرجح عدم الجواز .
>
> Based on my answer of the former question I prefer not allowing this kinds of interventions!