# If wife can't get pregnant, is it allowed to have a surrogate mother in this situation?

Tags: pregnancy

If wife is physically not able to get pregnant or the husband can't make her pregnant, but both want a child, is it allowed to have a surrogate mother in this situation??

Thank you for answers.

Comment: How are you planning to get the other woman pregnant?

Comment: This Post provides an answer http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7594/what-are-the-teachings-of-islam-about-sperm-donation/7598#7598

Comment: @ozbek with In-vitro-Fertilisation

Comment: @ozbek and Embryotransfer to surrogate mother is one option.

Comment: Then this question is an apparent duplicate of what @Medi1Saif has linked above.